# how to display images that saved in sql server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

how I can display images with img tag, that image name saved in database ?
I have a data table that save image name, but I can't assign image name to src address.

Comment: The image *name* is stored in the database, but where is the *image* stored?

Comment: Do you have the full image path saved?

Comment: If the image itself is stored in the database (its binary data) then a Google search for "asp.net display image from database" will find *tons* of examples of this.  Basically you want to create a separate server-side resource (an MVC action, an ASHX handler, even an ASPX page will work though it's unnecessary) for the sole purpose of serving the image.  Then the `src` address would be to that resource, with the identifier of the image to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have some http handler (like ashx file) to read the data from the database and then write that to the web browser. There's literally thousands of articles on how to do this if you do a search, but you may be interested in checking out [imageresizer](http://imageresizing.net/) as I believe they have a plugin that you can point to a database table to handle this.